# Swift 3 issue with sequence protocol extension on a generic linked list implementation.

Tags: generics, swift3, xcode8

Using swift 3, both via XCode 8.2 beta and the swift build cli, I am attempting to compile a playground illustrating an implementation of a linked list I found @ https://hugotunius.se/2016/07/17/implementing-a-linked-list-in-swift.html

The reported error is: **error: cannot convert value of type 'Node?' to expected argument type 'Node<_>?'**

The error occurs in the iterator extension.  The call to the constructor in the makeIterator function is the error line.

**return LinkedListIterator(startNode: start)**

I have tried a variety of ways to coerce the startNode into an acceptable type to no avail.  I'd love to know how this should be corrected and just as importantly why it is an error in the first place.  Thanks in advance.

The relevant code:

```
/* Node */
public class Node<T: Equatable> {
  typealias NodeType = Node<T>

  /// The value contained in this node
  public let value: T
  var next: NodeType? = nil
  var previous: NodeType? = nil

  public init(value: T) {
    self.value = value
  }
}

/*  Linked List */
public final class LinkedList<T: Equatable> {
public typealias NodeType = Node<T>

fileprivate var start: NodeType? {
    didSet {
        // Special case for a 1 element list
        if end == nil {
            end = start
        }
    }
}

fileprivate var end: NodeType? {
    didSet {
        // Special case for a 1 element list
        if start == nil {
            start = end
        }
    }
}

/// The number of elements in the list at any given time
public fileprivate(set) var count: Int = 0

/// Wether or not the list is empty. Returns `true` when
/// count is 0 and `false` otherwise
public var isEmpty: Bool {
    get {
        return count == 0
    }
}

/// Create a new LinkedList
///
/// - returns: An empty LinkedList
public init() {

}

/// Create a new LinkedList with a sequence
///
/// - parameter: A sequence
/// - returns: A LinkedList containing the elements of the provided      sequence
public init<S: Sequence>(_ elements: S) where S.Iterator.Element == T {
    for element in elements {
        append(value: element)
    }
  }
} 

public struct LinkedListIterator<T: Equatable>: IteratorProtocol {
public typealias Element = Node<T>

/// The current node in the iteration
private var currentNode: Element?

private init(startNode: Element?) {
    currentNode = startNode
}

public mutating func next() -> LinkedListIterator.Element? {
    let node = currentNode
    currentNode = currentNode?.next

    return node
 }
}
extension LinkedList: Sequence {
  public typealias Iterator = LinkedListIterator<T>

  public func makeIterator() -> LinkedList.Iterator {
    return LinkedListIterator(startNode: start)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a thoroughly misleading error message (which has already been filed as a bug, see [SR-2297](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2297)) – the problem is that your `LinkedListIterator`'s `init(startNode:)` initialiser is marked as `private`, and therefore inaccessible from within your `LinkedList` class.

One option would be to make it `fileprivate` instead:

```
fileprivate init(startNode: Element?) {
    currentNode = startNode
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Hamish.  It seems apparent in hindsight as I had already changed the protection level to fileprivate elsewhere in the code but was thrown off by the nature of the message.  I will try your suggested fix as soon as I have a chance and report back.

Comment: The protection level on the init method was indeed the problem.  Thanks again Hamish!

Comment: Happy to help @Chris :)